# Acessar uma variável de um decorator

Tags: python-3.x

fiz bastantes buscas, mas não consegui chegar onde penso que posso chegar.

Abaixo encontrei essas duas possibilidade de decorators, fiz uma pequena modificação para testes, vejam que dentro do `say_whee` eu quero acessar `quando` que está dentro do `count_calls`, isso é possível?

```py
import functools

class CountCalls:
    def __init__(self, func):
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func
        self.quando = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args[0] == "segunda":
            self.quando = "amanha"

        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

@CountCalls
def say_whee(dia):
    print(CountCalls.quando)

say_whee("segunda")
```

```py
import functools

def count_calls(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_count_calls(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper_count_calls.quando = None

        if args[0] == "segunda":
            wrapper_count_calls.quando = "amanha"

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_count_calls

@count_calls
def say_whee(dia):
    print(count_calls.quando)

say_whee("segunda")
```

Comment: É possível, com ressalvas importantes, mas a questão é: por que deseja usar decorador para isso?

Comment: Porque esse decorator será uma verificação de permissão de acesso. E nessa verificação terão algumas vars extras para uso dentro da função que utilizou o @decorator, não sei se ficou claro.

Comment: Realmente não parece ser a melhor solução, principalmente porque o estado interno do decorador será compartilhado entre as chamadas e isso pode trazer consequências negativas, principalmente se tratando de uma validação de permissões. Se precisará usar esses valores na função, por que então não passá-las como parâmetros?

Comment: No `say_whee` você diz?

Comment: certo, entendi, neste caso eu devo deletar a minha pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui encontrar a resposta para a minha questão, mas antes de chegarmos lá fique atento. Minha necessidade era usar o `decorator` para validar um acesso e consumir algumas variáveis através deste `decorator`, conforme me orientaram, **não** é recomendado para tal uso.

Então, antes de usar pense muito bem para qual finalidade será usado, para que não tenha problemas

```py
def funcDec(func):
    def wrapped(x, y):
        print(x)
        print(y)

        localVariable = "DOIS"
        # print(localVariable)
        funcDec.attrib = localVariable

        func(x, y)
        print("done with calling f1")

    return wrapped

@funcDec
def f1(x, y):
    print(x + y)
    print(funcDec.attrib)

f1(2, 3)
```